# How to disable the button with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to disable the link using it's id in Javascript. By default it's invisible as shown below. I will enable the link when the particular id came from back end.

**HTML**

```
<li id="viewroleId" style="display: none;">
    <a href="viewrole"><spring:message code="label.viewrole" /></a>
</li>
```

**Javascript:-**

```
if (key == 1) {
    var id = value;
    var div = document.getElementById(id);

    if(div != null){
        if (div.style.display == 'none' || div.style.display == '') {
            // Here it will display the link
            div.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

In the above Javascript code I will display the link, but I want to display and disable the link. How can I disable the link with CSS instead?

Comment: Check out [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

Comment: why not add disabled as an attribute? - also as a recommendation - never do inline css or js - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Comment: If I maintain ng-disabled then I need to give different names for each disabled href. Now the Id is coming from DB so I am able to display with It's id.

Comment: Can you build a fiddle to make this clearer? I don't see the reason why the link should be disabled if the li is hidden.

Comment: On IE family browsers you can use the *disabled* property of an element as in '<a href="adafdfd.asd" disabled> link content </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a rule like this in css

```
.disabled {
    display: block !important; /* since you set the element's display to none inline,
                                  we need to use !important flag (which is pretty bad)
                                  to override the inline style */
    pointer-events: none; /* Disable an element interaction, so it will not respond any event */
    color: #ccc; /* Gray out the text color to signify being disabled */
}
```

Now in your javascript, just give the element you want to disable the class `disabled` like so

```
if (key == 1) {
    var id = value;
    var div = document.getElementById(id);

    if(div != null){
        if (div.className.indexOf('disabled') === -1) {
            // Your element will be visible, and disabled
            div.className += ' disabled';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dummy what do you mean by className here

Comment: `className` is the property that allows you to manipulate the `class` attribute of each `HTMLElement`

Comment: I am getting div.className is ""(empty)

Comment: You should read my code again, the if block `if (div.className.indexOf('disabled') === -1)` checks if the element pointed to by `div` has the class `disabled` or not, if it does not, it means the element is not disabled, so we add the class `disabled` to it to disable it, we check its classes instead of its `.style.display` like you did

Comment: I am getting Uncaught Natives disabled

Comment: I think your best bet is to just follow @Kevin's suggestion to use `ngDisabled`, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel. P/S, I am not sure why you are getting that error

Comment: *(courtesy of thechnomark.in admin) lol  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXjfsHektMM

Comment: @BekimBacaj did you just seriously assume I watched that video and stole his solution? **Let the hate flow through you** (facepalm yourself). Just because you don't know how to do something, you assume everyone else is as clueless as you are

Comment: No @Dummy I didn't, but I assume you did, but seriously lol why so serious :D

Comment: @BekimBacaj you clearly impiled that, if you don't have any nice and helpful suggestion, I suggest keeping it to yourself

Comment: I gave my nice and helpful sugestion, and now I'm totally convinced that you did steal the solution from that Hindu guy.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Keep telling yourself that, I aint have to explain anything to anybody, but just remember there is always someone out there who is better than you. **nice suggestion**, don't use the word **nice** ever so lightly

Comment: @BekimBacaj what do you mean by Hindu guy

Comment: this does not disable the button. It only prevents "clicking" on the button with a pointing device. Pressing tab until the button has the focus and then pressing space will still "click" the bottom (the click event will be emitted)

Comment: @gman Did you read and understand the question's title?

Comment: @TrashCan. I did, did you? The title is  "How to disable the button with css". This answer does not disable the button. The button is still enabled. You can't click it with the mouse but you can tab to it and press space which will still "click" it (you'll get a click event)

Comment: @gman Right, but how else do you disable it *with CSS*?

Comment: You can't disable it with css

Answer (score 0):

If your app is based on Angular use ng-if, this is the "natural way"

```
<a ng-if="true" href="yourlink.html">Link<a/>
<a ng-if="!true" href="#">Link<a/>
```

Is better to try to overwrite browser native implementation (link...);